# Skip With Collection in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Here is my cypher query

```
MATCH (notification:Notification)-[:CREATED_BY]->(user:User)
MATCH (notification)-[:NOTIFICATION_COUNTRY]->(country:Country)
WHERE notification.status='PENDING' AND notification.type='SIMPLE'
RETURN collect({id:id(notification),message:notification.message,updated:notification.lastUpdatedDate,edited:user.username,country:country.name})  as notifications
 LIMIT 25
```

i want SKIP,LIMIT on notification.But, here i am returning collection of notifications,so how can i use SKIP with collection, is  there any another way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SKIP` and `LIMIT` together with `WITH`, and thus limiting the notifications before creating your collection :

```
MATCH (notification:Notification)-[:CREATED_BY]->(user:User)
MATCH (notification)-[:NOTIFICATION_COUNTRY]->(country:Country)
WHERE notification.status='PENDING' AND notification.type='SIMPLE'
WITH notification
SKIP 10
LIMIT 20
RETURN collect({id:id(notification),message:notification.message,updated:notification.lastUpdatedDate,edited:user.username,country:country.name})  as notifications
```

Comment: thanks @ Christophe, it is working fine. i want to ask one more thing, can we optimize this query and get response more faster then this one. i am new to cypher, want more tips to get response more faster or right way to write query.

Comment: if you create an index on notification.type and/or status